# Software suggestion for PDE simulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software

I want to simulate partial differential equations problems.
I tried using OpenFoam, but it won't install in my pc, due to some errors.

So, I was hoping if anyone could recommend me a free and  Good/better substitution for OpenFoam and perhaps with easy UI and working.

Thanks.

Comment: [The Dedalus code works well](http://dedalus-project.org/).

Comment: Why not try the free FreeFem++?